# How to find the available amount on a particular credit card using papal API.

Tags: paypal

Before sending the  transaction to the PayPal, I  have to  check the required transaction amount is available on card or not. If available I will proceed with transaction else  I will send a message to user. Please let me know how to check the available amount  on particular credit card.

Thanks,
Sudheer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. The only way I know of to see if an amount is available is to put a [hold on the card](https://www.forumcu.com/Holds). That can only be done (as far as I know) through a merchant account.